# Is it possible to share a field between Matrix Blocks?

Tags: matrix, block-types

I'm attempting to do some advanced layout orchestration using Matrix blocks. I'll need different blocks types – Image, Quote, Body – that can be combined, but they'll each need to share a few fields that allow their layout to be customized, such as Padding, Alignment, or Width. I'd rather not have to create the exact same field (e.g. Alignment could be a 4-option Dropdown) for each block type, but there doesn't seem to be a way to share fields between Matrix Blocks the same way you can share them between Sections.

Am I correct that there is no better way to accomplish this than just recreate the shared fields for each block type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct - currently Matrix fields are not global, so you'll need to recreate them if you want to use them in other Matrix blocks.

Comment: Are there updates to this? Or is this still true about Matrix fields? Thank you.

Comment: Yup... still true.

Comment: is there a feature request related to this? I'd like to vote on it :-)

Comment: @userAW yup! https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/823

Comment: One day.... I hope : )